# How to install node js tools for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, visual-studio

I'm fairly new to web development (coming from app development). I'm trying to use visual studio 2019 on mac and I don't see a way to install the node js extensions or 'workload' that a lot of tutorials are recommending.

How do I get started with node js and react development in VS 2019?

Comment: VS or VSCode? any way VS is not a good IDE for web development

Answer (score 2):

VS for Mac is rather different from VS for Windows, and does not [yet](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17349802-node-js-project-support) support Node.js.

Instead, you should use Visual Studio Code, which is the same on all platforms and does.